# Youtube CommentThreads api Insert not working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to Use Youtube api v3 to comment on video and getting this error but my request data is correct according to documentation.
Here is my code.
Using oauth the code setting access_token like this

oauth.setCredentials(tokens);

```
 var channelId = "UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA";
                var request = Youtube.commentThreads.insert({
                          "part": [
                                    "snippet"
                          ],
                          "resource": {
                                    "snippet": {
                                              "videoId": "qfuFeUnAm8E",
                                              "topLevelComment": {
                                                        "snippet": {
                                                                  "textOriginal": "best video"
                                                        }
                                              },
                                              "channelId": channelId
                                    }
                          }
                }, (err, data) => {
                          if (err) {
                                    console.log(err, 'errerrerr')
                          }
                          if (data) {
                                    console.log(data, 'datadata');
                          }
                });
```

This is the error i'm getting in return

```
  errors: [
{
  message: "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>commentThread</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.",
  domain: 'youtube.commentThread',
  reason: 'processingFailure',
  location: 'body',
  locationType: 'other'
}
```

]

This is the authentication or authorization code generating everytime

```
"tokens": {
    "access_token": "[redacted]",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expiry_date": 1655195240477
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the authorization code you are using.

Comment: Updated code in question

Comment: Let me rephrase that.  May i see the code you are using to get the access to the api.  The code you are using that returns the access token which you just added to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider testing out your insert in the [try me](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert?apix=true)  The object you have created doesnt look right at all.

You should consult [comments resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments#resource) for the proper format of the body.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for youtube.comments.insert
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.comments.insert({
      "resource": {
        "snippet": {
          "videoId": "qfuFeUnAm8E",
          "channelId": "UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA"
        }
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```